# Python super class error

Tags: python, django, oop

here i m posting a part of code which i don't understand.

Please help me with that:

**Code-**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['assigned'].extra.update(
            {'to_field_name': User.USERNAME_FIELD})
```

But when i try this code i got syntax error on `super()`, i don't know why??

> python version 2.7 doesn't support this syntax super should have
>   argument in python2

And what actually this code is mean??

thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't have any problems with this fragment. Can you post something a little bigger that demonstrates the problem and also the exact stack trace you get? Plus, are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: i am using python 2.7

Comment: That's a python 3 example  and even though it is syntactically correct, it won't execute properly on 2.7. Any reason you are learning 2.7? Unless you are specifically restricted to using 2.x (old code), you should be learning and using 3.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs on `super`:

```
super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
   super(type) -> unbound super object
   super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)
   Typical use to call a cooperative superclass method:
   class C(B):
       def meth(self, arg):
           super(C, self).meth(arg)
```

You gave no arguments to `super`, so it does not know what to do on Python2.  For a solution that works on Python2 and Python3, try `super(C, self)`

Comment: This is true for python2 and will be a problem but it doesn't explain the syntax error.